# Eclipse WindowBuilder generates forms- 1.3.0.jar and miglayout15-swing.jar files in Project directory

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, layout, windowbuilder

I'm having a problem with Eclipse.
I was using the Google WindowBuilder for my very first time and as I watched
into my project directory, there were two new .jar-files 
"forms- 1.3.0.jar" and "miglayout15-swing.jar".

Which kind of files are this? I think they aren't even metioned in my source code.
The java application can be run without the files, but I noticed that 
no System.out.print commands are executed.

When deleting the files, Eclipse marks the project folder with a red exclamation mark.

Anyone knowing this issue? 
How can I get rid of these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file 'forms-1.3.0.jar' is used by the visual swing (or other) editor.

1. Navigate to the folder eclipse is housed in.
2. Using the search bar, search for "forms-1.3.0". **Not the zipped folder, the jar file above it**
3. Drag it onto the project file with the exclamation mark.

Do the same thing with "miglayout15-swing.jar".

I don't know how to get rid of them, but if you're asking how to get rid of the exclamation mark, this is it.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the project in Eclipse, select Properties | Java Build Path. Under the tab Libraries select forms-1.3.0.jar and click on Remove.